# Regular expression for getting string part

Tags: php, regex, string

I have some string like

```
Shp 1,737 Plenty Rd, Mill Park VIC 3082
560 High St, Preston VIC 3072
217 Mickleham Rd, Tullamarine VIC 3043
```

from these i need "VIC" . Can anyone help me to find out a solution using regex or php string function[image]

This is the actual strings... that read from an excel sheet i want the states name from these string like, **NSW, ACT, VIC** etc

Comment: value of VIC or only VIC?? please paste your desired output

Comment: Why do you need a regex? Just create a string "VIC".

Comment: do u want  VIC 3082560, VIC 3072210, VIC 3043??

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712320/regular-expression-for-getting-string-part/5712353#5712353) will get them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/(?P<state>[A-Z]{2,3})\s\d{4}$/m', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches['state']);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "VIC"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "VIC"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "VIC"
}
```

This uses a regex in multiline mode to match the 2 or 3 capital letters preceding a whitespace character and a 4 digit postcode.

I called it `state` because I live in Australia and these are all Australian states :)

Comment: but is there any possibility to have 2 letter for states like SA

Comment: @Nisanth: no problem, just use `{2,3}` instead of `{3}`

Answer (score 3):

if it's always next-to-last, just split the string on space and take the penultimate element.

Answer (score 0):

To get vic with its value:

```
$getvic = substr($myString,-8,-7);
```

To get just VIC:

```
$getvic = substr($myString,-8,-2);
```